# Why does SwiftUI only apply the first modifier when I apply duplicated ones to a View?

Tags: swiftui

```swift
Text("Hello, world!")
    .fontWeight(.heavy) // this is applied to the Text
    .fontWeight(.thin) // this is not applied
```

As I understand it, SwiftUI re-produces a new View as it goes through the modifiers(like a pure function).

So, in the code above, I thought that the **last modifier** applied should be the one finally reflected in the View(`.fontWeight(.thin)`).

However, in reality, the **first one** applied is reflected in the View.
[image]

Why is it that when there are multiple duplicate modifiers applied to the View, the first one is applied instead of the last?

Here's another example

```swift
Text("Hello, world!") 
    .foregroundColor(.red) // this is applied
    .foregroundColor(.yellow) // this is ignored
    .foregroundColor(.blue) // this is ignored
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it just ignores the duplicates since it's obviously a programmer error.

Comment: I would guess it's a bit like when you have some ```Text``` in a container such as a ```VStack```. You can set a font on the container, but if you also set a font on the text itself then it takes priority. So it seems the modifiers applied "closest" to the view always take prioriy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. Your understanding is generally correct: When a modifier is applied to a view, it wraps that view in a new view as defined by the modifier.

However, you need to distinguish between

1. **container modifiers** and
2. **environment modifiers**.

(There's probably no official distinction, but that's how I categorize them to help figuring out what's going on.)

- **Examples for container modifiers:**

  - `frame`, `padding`, `overlay`, `background`, `border`, `cornerRadius`, `clipShape` etc.
- **Examples for environment modifiers:**

  - `font`, `foregroundColor`, and all kinds of styles like `buttonStyle`, `pickerStyle`, `listStyle` etc.

### Container Modifiers

While every modifier technically produces a new wrapper view with the view that it's applied to as its child, only container views work "bottom to top". For example, if you apply an `overlay` modifier multiple times as follows:

```
myView
    .overlay(Color.red)
    .overlay(Color.blue)
```

the last modifier will take preceded in the end. It works exactly as you would imagine:

1. We start with drawing `myView`.
2. Then `myView` is wrapped in an `Overlay` which is – by definition – drawn on top of the view it's applied to.
3. The `Overlay<MyView>` is wrapped in another `Overlay` which is drawn on top of the compound view, so the result will be `blue`.

(Note that for the `background` modifier it's the other way around as it is drawn behind the view it's applied to by definition. So when using `background` instead of `overlay` in the code example above, the background would be `red`.)

### Environment Modifiers

... are different. They define an environment value that is provided to the inner views and not visible outside. (You can access some of these values with the `@Environment` property wrapper in a view.)

They do not actually draw anything, but provide information to inner views on how *they* should draw something.

The important question to ask is:

### Who draws what?

A view only knows how to draw itself. For example, a `Rectangle` or a `VStack` doesn't know how to draw letters. Only a `Text` knows how to do that. So the `Text` will ultimately need the information which font to use. And that's what you pass up the hierarchy with the `.font` modifier.

It's the same with a `listStyle`: Only a `List` knows how to draw itself and what a `listStyle` means, so it can access this value that you inject with the `.listStyle` modifier up the hierarchy.

If you think about it this way, it makes total sense that the environment modifier closest to the view that uses it takes precedence. It simply overrides any modifier that follows.

If this was not the case, the whole environment approach would not work. You would not be able to set a base font (or foregroundColor) for your app  and customize it for some selected labels that you want to highlight.

The following example only works because modifiers closest to a view take precedence:

```
VStack {
    Text("Headline")
        .font(.headline)
    Text("Longer text with a description..."
    Text("Another normal paragraph...")
    Text("The last paragraph..."
}
.font(.body)
```

If the outer-most modifier would win, all texts in this example would be rendered with a `.body` font as the `.headline` would be overridden. Hope this helps.